# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors , android

Tags: android, manifest, android-workmanager

I am using work manager in my application

Work manager version `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'`

And in the manifest I have added

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

And added this at application tag in manifest  `tools:replace="android:authorities"`

When I build the application I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.manifest.ManifestHelperKt.mergeManifests(ManifestHelper.kt:87)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest.doFullTaskAction(ProcessApplicationManifest.kt:144)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:112)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.access$handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:65)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:65)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
```

In the manifest merge I see this error

```
Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute android:authorities, but no new value specified My_Application.app main manifest (this file), line 5 Error: Validation failed, exiting My_Application.app main manifest (this file)
```

And this is my application class

```
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

}

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
        .build()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong config:

**Since WorkManager 2.6, App Startup is used internally within WorkManager. To provide a custom initializer you need to remove the androidx.startup node.**

```
<!-- If you want to disable android.startup completely. -->
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove">
 </provider>
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#remove-default